# store jsp page in variable

Tags: php, jsp

Can I do something similar like below code in JSP?

```
ob_start();
include 'app/views/sections/header.php';
$header = ob_get_clean();
```

Then i need to print the page under another JSP?

Comment: what you want to achieve in jsp? Please explain a bit more? A person that knows JSP but might not understand it PHP and vice-verse.

Comment: I want to use a jsp page multiple times on a same page with a loop, and fill every page with different data